# Perform validation on input tag before form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have form which is POSTING all the values but I need to perform validation on phone number input field.
I have tried to apply click event on input tag using id but then HTML5 validation(required) goes off

```
<form name="frm" method="post" id="callForm" >
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX" required/>
    <input id="submitbtn" value="Call Me!" type="submit"  />
</form>
```

Js:

```
$('#submitbtn').click(function() {
    if((frm.phone.value).length < 10)
    {
        alert("Phone number should be minimum 10 digits");
        frm.phone.focus(); 
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

link to code pen: https://codepen.io/rahulv/pen/rrwBdq

JavaScript:

```
$("input[type='tel']").each(function(){
  $(this).on("change keyup paste", function (e) {
  var output,
  $this = $(this),
  input = $this.val();

if(e.keyCode != 8) {
  input = input.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  var area = input.substr(0, 3);
  var pre = input.substr(3, 3);
  var tel = input.substr(6, 4);
  if (area.length < 3) {
    output = "(" + area;
  } else if (area.length == 3 && pre.length < 3) {
    output = "(" + area + ")" + " " + pre;
  } else if (area.length == 3 && pre.length == 3) {
    output = "(" + area + ")" + " " + pre + "-" + tel;
  }

  $this.val(output);
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$('#submitbtn').click(function() {
    if((frm.phone.value).length > 0)
    {
        if((frm.phone.value).length < 10)
        {
            alert("Phone number should be minimum 10 digits");
            frm.phone.focus(); 
            return false;
        }

        $( "#callForm" ).submit();
    }

});
```

Comment: no this doesn't work either. html5 validation is being by passed. if you dont apply any JS and click on submit button you will se HTML5 required validation it will say "please enter this field" but it goes away

Comment: Yep!! thanks. it works.. is there a way I can optimize this code I mean logic for validation?

Comment: yes! try it  `<input pattern=".{10,}"   required title="10 characters minimum" type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX" required/>`

Answer (score 0):

Disable html5 validation on your form

```
<form name="frm" method="post" id="callForm" novalidate>
```

Add the 'novalidate' attribute.

Comment: I need html5 validation along with atleast 10 digit for phone number input